# Creating custom claim with the command \newtheorem{claim}{Claim} in a proof

Tags: environments, customize

Sorry for this silly question, but after I create the `claim` environment `\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}`, how do I custom each `claim` temporarily/locally?

For example, how do I want to name my claims in the proof to be "funny claim", "hard claim" etc...or remove the numeration labels 1,2,3 for the claims

The codes

```latex
\begin{claim}[funny claim]
\end{claim}
```

or

```latex
\begin{claim*}
\end{claim*}
```

are not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{xxxxx}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{#3}
\theoremstyle{xxxxx}
\newtheorem{claim}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{claim}[Funny Claim]
\lipsum[2]
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}[Hard Claim]
\lipsum[2]
\end{claim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define an unnumbered theorem type with variable name. With this approach you need not guess parameters and can also give an attribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\claimname}{}
\newtheorem*{claiminner}{\claimname}
\newenvironment{claim}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\claimname}{#1}\claiminner}
 {\endclaiminner}

\begin{document}

\begin{claim}{Funny claim}
This claim is funny.
\end{claim}

\begin{claim}{Hard claim}[Euler]
This is harder and has been proved by someone else.
\end{claim}

\end{document}
```

[image]